# How to join two data frames with different lengths on time and column in pandas?

Tags: pandas, join, group-by

I want to join a pandas dataframe with column x and key k with the mean value of x for each time,key pair. The code below fails with:

```
ValueError: len(left_on) must equal the number of levels in the index of "right"
```

Is there a better way to join on time/key?

```
# Import required packages
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

# Create a datetime variable for today
base = datetime.datetime.today()
# Create a list variable that creates 365 days of rows of datetime values
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 365)]

date_list = date_list + date_list

# Create a list variable of 365 numeric values
score_list = list(np.random.randint(low=1, high=1000, size=365*2))
key_list = list(np.random.randint(low=1, high=5, size=365*2))

df = pd.DataFrame()

# Create a column from the datetime variable
df['datetime'] = date_list
# Convert that column into a datetime datatype
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
# Set the datetime column as the index
df.index = df['datetime']
# Create a column from the numeric score variable
df['score'] = score_list
df['key'] = key_list

dfGroup = df.groupby(["datetime", "key"]).mean()


# JOIN PRIMARY TABLE WITH GROUPED TAB
df.join(other=dfGroup,on=["datetime"])
```

Comment: The code block above was mostly taken from http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_group_data_by_time.html

Comment: df's index is datetime and dfGrouby has a multiindex(datetime and key).  Thats what the error is telling you.

Comment: Actually, following suggestion above and creating table with new index works with code below. Is there a cleaner way that doesn't require redefining indices for each join on a different key?                                                               
    `df2 = df.set_index(['datetime','key'])
    df2.join(dfGroup, rsuffix="mean")`

Comment: `join` doesn't require indices.  You can join column to column.  You just can't  mix the two.  However, `merge` will allow a join from a col to an index

Answer (score 0):

`df.merge(dfGroup.reset_index(), on=['datetime', 'key'])`